# Installing ubuntu 14.0.4 besides windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

Okay here is the problem. I already have 3 partitions in windows 1.Windows default 2.Where my softwares are and 3.Where all my Media files are. My question is what if i shrink each partition 10 GB that would be around 35 Gb total free space and manually create 3 partitions for ubuntu ie 1 for swap another for root and next for home? Because ubuntu doesnt seem to let me create more than 4 partitions. What is the problem in doing this i am planning to use minitool partition software for this? If not suggest me a better way where i must not lose any of my existing data/OS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make you BACKUP anyway whether you use minitool partition wizard, Gparted from ubuntu or `fdsik`.

Now some rules and explanation about partitions:

The total data storage space of a PC HDD can contain at most four *primary* partitions, or alternatively three *primary* partitions and an *extended* partition.

[image]

Here is an example showing both: `/proc/partitions/` and `fdisk` and their corresponding. As you can see at the picture, `fisk` tells it by `Extended` whereas `/proc/partitions/` provides a code, a number: 1-4 for primary and extended partitions  and 5+ for logical partitions. It is an Extended partition marked with red by me to highlight that logical partitions start with number 5 right after the Extended Partition.

[image]

To sum up, you are going to create ( or if exists, "redesign" manually) an extended partition inside of which you are allowed to have a lot of logical disks. You can operate in either *minitool partition wizard* or *gparted*. I trust both. In both I resized many drives many times. Don't forget to save precious data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't create more than 4 partitions, it sounds like you have a DOS partition table and the problem is that you are creating a primary partition for number 4.

If your 4th partition is created as an extended partition instead, you should be able to make any number of logical partitions within the extended partition. You can only have one extended partition.

In Linux, traditionally the primary partition devices will be sda1, sda2 etc, while the logical partition devices start at sda5.